# How to add field or information in orgchart kendo ui

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

i have json data like this:

```
  {
    "item_id": "195",
    "item_desc": "Fuel Cost",
    "parent_pi_kode": "193",
    "parent_pid_desc": "Blasting Cost",
    "eoy_target": 0.2,
    "eoy_actual": 0.32,
    "ytd_plan": 0.13,
    "ytd_actual": 0.14,
    "achi_pi": 107.692307,
    "achi_ia": 0.0,
    "achi_ra": 0.0,
    "achi_ip": 0.0,
    "has_child": true,
    "is_expanded": true
  },
  {
    "item_id": "194",
    "item_desc": "AN Cost",
    "parent_pi_kode": "193",
    "parent_pid_desc": "Blasting Cost",
    "eoy_target": 0.2,
    "eoy_actual": 0.32,
    "ytd_plan": 0.1,
    "ytd_actual": 0.12,
    "achi_pi": 120.0,
    "achi_ia": 0.0,
    "achi_ra": 0.0,
    "achi_ip": 0.0,
    "has_child": true,
    "is_expanded": true
  },
  {
    "item_id": "196",
    "item_desc": "Oil Cost",
    "parent_pi_kode": "193",
    "parent_pid_desc": "Blasting Cost",
    "eoy_target": 0.2,
    "eoy_actual": 0.32,
    "ytd_plan": 0.08,
    "ytd_actual": 0.1,
    "achi_pi": 125.0,
    "achi_ia": 0.0,
    "achi_ra": 0.0,
    "achi_ip": 0.0,
    "has_child": true,
    "is_expanded": true
  }
]
```

i want to make orgchart that can expand and collapse like https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/orgchart/events#, but kendo ui orgchart only show 2 information (name, and position), meanwhile i have 9 information to show (item_desc, eoy_target, eoy_actual, ytd_plan, ytd_actual, achi_pi, achi_ra, achi_ip, achi_ia). how can i custom kendo orgchart so i can make orgchart with 9 information, by the way i dont need avatar field to this

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into using the template feature of Kendo. The demo located here https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/orgchart/templates will get you started.

Essentially you can define whatever HTML you want to use in your template, so you can customize the look of the org chart to be exactly what you need. You define the template list this:

```
    $("#orgchart").kendoOrgChart({
        template:
            "<div class='custom'>" +
            "<div><img alt='Kendo UI for jQuery OrgChart #:name #' src=' #: avatar #'/></div>" +
            "<span>Name: <strong> #: name # </strong></span>" +                
            "</div>",
        groupHeaderTemplate: "<i> #: field #</i>: <strong>#: value # </strong>",
        groupField: "position",
        dataSource: data
    });
```

Using that template value, you assign the HTML string you want.